# Angular 10 Angular material checkbox array not passing values

Tags: angular, angular-material

My application is Angular 10 and my forms are Reactive I implemented checkbox array in my application it does not pass the values. when I check the checkboxes and submit my form it does not pass values of checked days.

my component.ts

```
 this.holidayForm= this._formBuilder.group({
    RepeatTypeID: ['', null],
    SelectedWeekDays: new FormArray([]),
  });
```

my component html

```
  <div  *ngFor="let wdItems of WeekDays; let i=index">
            <mat-checkbox formArrayName="SelectedWeekDays" [value]="wdItems.Weekdayid" >{{wdItems.Weekdayname}}</mat-checkbox>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](https://netbasal.com/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-angular-forms-57eb8e846d21):

Create a FormArray like this:

```js
this.fg = new FormGroup({
   optionControls: new FormArray([
      new FormControl(true),
      new FormControl(false),
   ])
})
```

Render the options, based on these controls:

```js
  <div *ngFor=”let optionControl of fg.optionControls; let i=index”>
   <input type=”checkbox” [formControl]=”optionControl”/> {{  myOriginalArray[i].someProperty }}
  </div>
```

Now `fg.optionControls.value` is an array of boolean values. eg.: `[true, false]`.
If this is not enough, you can continue with converting this datastructure into a format which serves your needs.

Good luck, I hope I could help.

Comment: I need array of values, because I have to apply other logic's in backend

Comment: I extended my answer with a pretty useful link

Comment: I updated my codes like the example (let wdItems of holidayForm.SelectedWeekDays) i get error Property 'SelectedWeekDays' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'

Comment: I think he meant instead of true/false as values, he is looking to using at other custom values. Came across this post because i do not want true/false as values but from certain arrays. [value] did not work.